# Enthought Canopy does not read data from or write data to csv files for Python

Tags: python-2.7, csv, import, enthought

To my knowledge, the Code Editor application from Enthought Canopy is not able to read from or write to a csv file when using the csv module in Python 2.7.

As far as I master the technical knowledge of what is happening on the background the problem, if any, occurs when the for loop is called to print the data in the csv file. The program simply prints out nothing. Even if an additional print function is added to the for loop, nothing happens. It seems like the whole for loop is neglected. There must be something goes on wrong since the code does work in the Python 2.7 software program itself. The picture in the link below depicts the code and the outcome in the original Python 2.7 on the left and in the Enthought Canopy version on the right.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0PuA.jpg

Could someone please inform me what hinders the code to execute the read and write functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way that I have been able to replicate this problem is to have an empty "coord.csv" file in my Canopy working directory. Otherwise python will raise an IOError exception. Your Canopy working directory is set to "C:\Users\Peter-Jan", but it seems like everything else is in "W:\Dropbox\School\UGent\2elEOR...". Try either changing your working directory to the location of "coord.csv", or if it is in the same location as "_read_write_csv.py" select "Keep Directory Synced To Editor" in the drop down menu.

Comment: This, apparently, was indeed the problem. After changing my working directory to my editor directory, via "Change to Editor Directory", I could read data from and read out data to csv. files. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Enthought Support here. This is odd. I cannot reproduce this problem in the current version, Canopy 1.5.5. From the ticket that you submitted to us, your Canopy version is 1.4.1.

To update Canopy to the latest version, please see [this article](https://support.enthought.com/entries/61798124-Canopy-shows-no-updates-available-reinstalling-from-the-website).

Comment: After updating to the latest version, Canopy 1.5.5, I get the same outcome as with the previous version.